# Execute PowerShell function on change of path

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to execute some code (eg. a function, script block, cmdlet etc) whenever the current path changes in the PowerShell console or ISE?

The scenario I am thinking of is to modify some environment variables and dot source some location-specific PowerShell functions depending on the current folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options.  You can remove the "cd" alias and then write a "cd" function and add the desired logic.  The downside to this approach is that if someone uses Set-Location, your function is bypassed.  Another option is to create a proxy command for Set-Location. Shay (and Kirk) have a video on how to do this [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/archive/2012/03/30/leveraging-proxy-functions-in-powershell.aspx).  The nice thing about this approach is that the built-in ways to change dir (cd and Set-Location) will go through your proxy command.

Comment: The proxy command approach looks promising. The proxy extension is here - [link](http://pspx.codeplex.com/)